# How first perform the function and then send a static file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have following code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //???
});

app.listen(80);
```

How first perform the function and then send a static file?

Now sent only a static file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(app.router);  //<------------this way
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    //actions
    //send index
    next();
});

app.listen(80);
```